# fastlane screengrab and snapshot

Tags: android, ios, fastlane

I'm using fastlane tools (https://fastlane.tools) for automating all screenshots for my iOS and Android apps. The tool works very well and I'm happy with it. The problem i'm having is that when I have mixpanel events and other analytics running on the app the app will run those events during screenshots. Is there a way to "detect" in code that it's a screenshot event with simulators?

Basically, I want some sort of if statement but not sure how to tell its from fastlane. I have thoroughly read through the documentation and wasn't able to find anything for this, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current solution involves simply checking if the user is running on a simulator or is running in debug mode. In which case, it doesn't perform the code I want to filter out.